# Exposing a base class destructor as virtual means breaking ABI backward compatiblity?

Tags: c++, abi

I have the following interface class:

```cpp
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Base
{
public:
  Base() = default;

  virtual rtype method1() = 0;
  virtual rtype method2() = 0;
···
  virtual rtype methodN() = 0;
}
```

And the following child class:

```cpp
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Child
{
public:
  Child() = default;
  virtual ~Child() = default;


  virtual rtype method1()
  {
    ···
  }

  virtual rtype method2()
  {
    ···
  }
···
  virtual rtype methodN()
  {
    ···
  }
}
```

Both classes are exposed in a shared library. Now, I want to make the following change to the classes:

Base class:

```cpp
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Base
{
public:
  Base() = default;
  // This is the change
  virtual ~Base() = default;

  virtual rtype method1() = 0;
  virtual rtype method2() = 0;
···
  virtual rtype methodN() = 0;
}
```

Child class:

```cpp
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Child
{
public:
  Child() = default;
  // This is the change
  ~Child() override = default;


  virtual rtype method1()
  {
    ···
  }

  virtual rtype method2()
  {
    ···
  }
···
  virtual rtype methodN()
  {
    ···
  }
}
```

So my question here is making such change will break ABI backward compatiblity?
My asumption here is that it will as I am adding a new entry to the Base class vtable, but I ran
**abi-compliance-checker** and it reported no problems... so what do you think?

Comment: I'd guess that abi-compliance-checker is broken.

Comment: '__attribute__((visibility("default")))'  is actually not the same thing as `__declspec(dllexport) and__declspec(dllimport)`. In fact is is the same as `class Foo;` so noting actually changed. In case if linux G++, when you are building shared library all symbols going to be exported unlike windows DLL - where you need to export/import public classes/variables/functions

Comment: 2. If you need  hiden visibility by default add `-fvisibility=hidden` to compiler comand line options.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: This most certainly breaks the ABI.

Comment: As you said, @VictorGubin, visibility and declspec(export) is not the same thing. I actually  did some translation there, my class actually uses a macro which for linux translates into default visibility (having set -fvisibility=hidden) and for windows declspec(export).

In the case of Windows I've tried compiling it and I am able to see a new entry added to the vtable, but in the case of GCC 9.3/Clang-6 I am unable to find new entries into the vtable, so there's something I should be missing, right?